# Why is $\limsup S_n $ a constant in $[-\infty,\infty]$ according to Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law?

Tags: probability-theory

This question is based on a statement in Durrett's book, 4th edition, page 181, in the proof the theorem in that page.

$S_n = X_1+...+X_n$, with $X_i$ iid.

I'm supposed to notice that  $\limsup_n S_n =c$ is a permutable event, and hence, by the Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law, we have $\exists_{c \in [-\infty,\infty]} P(\limsup_n S_n =c)\in \{0,1\}$.

But why should it be $1$ and not $0$?

Comment: Well hang on, $\limsup S_n(\omega)$ exists and is in $[-\infty, \infty]$ for *any* $\omega$, you don't need Hewitt-Savage to prove that. Are you sure that's what the text says?

Comment: @JackM First line of the proof on page 181: «Theorem 4.1.1 [Hewitt-Savage law] implies limsup $S_n$ is a constant $c \in [-\infty, \infty]$.

Comment: Okay, then the formula after "Hence, by..." in your question is not quite right. You are trying to prove $\exists c\ P(\limsup S_n=c)\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: To clarify: the event $\liminf S_n\in[-\infty, \infty]$ is indeed a permutable event... because it's equal to the entire probability space!

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual argument is slightly subtle. Note that $\limsup S_n$ is a well-defined random variable, so let's examine its distribution. We would like to prove that this distribution is actually a Dirac distribution centered on some point. For any particular constant $c$, the event

$$\limsup S_n\leq c$$

is a permutable event, and thus occurs with probability either $0$ or $1$. So the cumulative distribution function of $\limsup S_n$ only takes on the values $0$ or $1$, which implies the distribution is indeed Dirac.

Maybe a slightly more intuitive way of doing this is to use, instead of a constant $c$, an arbitrary interval $I$. So we have that for any interval, $\limsup S_n\in I$ occurs with probability $0$ or $1$, and so the distribution is Dirac.

Comment: Hi Jack, many thanks ;) +1